# no ip unreachables good or bad

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, isp

Using following command on my cisco WAN interface is good or bad?

```
no ip redirects
no ip unreachables
no ip proxy-arp
no cdp enable
```

are there any advantage?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I personally enable cdp/lldp at least internally (some exchange points usually forbid them though).

**no ip unreachable** is not a good idea: it breaks PMTU discovery for instance. http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/oct/9/disabling-unreachables-breaks-pmtud/ .

ICMP unreachables can be rate limited though.